# Why are my objects 'exploding'?

Tags: modeling, animation, modifiers, transforms

I have just encountered an issue with a model I have created. When I scrub through the timeline parts of the model seem to explode away from each other. To my knowledge I have not added any modifiers to it and do not want this to happen!
Here are a couple of images which illustrate the problem:

At Frame 0
[image: Frame 0]

At Frame 10
[image: Frame 10]

Here is a link to the blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x3pw00lmhvw0tut/Cabin.blend

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set several of the roof pieces as [rigid bodies](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Sergof/GSoC2012/Documentation). To delete the rigid body and all of the motion calculated from it Select the roof pices, then in the *physics* tab of the tool bar press remove.
[image: physics tab]
You can also get to the physics settings in the *physics* tab of the properties window.  [image: properties window]

Comment: Thank you! That was it. Not sure how that happened!